# Raised white patch on the shoulder area behind bearded dragon's head

Tags: bearded-dragon

Beardie has a raised white patch around the shoulder area behind her head.
It doesn't seem painful or hasn't changed her eating habits.
What is the cause of the patch?

Comment: please add some more details,how old is it and how long have you had it what are your setup and how long has it been looking like that.

Comment: If in doubt, go see a vet instead of asking strangers on the internet. Most animals hide signs of pain and discomfort as long as possible (especially reptiles), because any sign of weakness means they end up as a snack to the next predator. Doesn't mean they don't feel the discomfort / pain, though. A vet can assess her overall health, maybe find problems you haven't even noticed yet, and give you advice on how to change her diet or habitat to keep her healthy.

Comment: Its actually my grandsons lizard he has had her over 2 years 40 gallon reptile tank with screen top water/soaking bowl heat lamp day light bulb on 12 hours off 12 Mostly eats crickets dusted with calcium powder 4 doz large crickets a week along with fruit and veggies but really does not eat this maybe a nibble or two, Is suppose to be a female according to pet store has had her since she was a hatchling, Uses paper towels to line the bottom of the crate She has looked like this for over a year now is still active loves to take baths but only about once a month